# Same query returning thousands of records in Access 2016 but only a hundred in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have an MS Access DB I'm working in and there's a linked table connected to a SQL Server DB. I'm creating a make table query and using the linked table as the connection. The purpose of the query is to pull in records with a termination date in the last 30 days.

My query in MSSMS looks like this

```
select name,title,u_term_date 
from dbo.sys_user 
where u_term_date >= DATEADD(day,-30, GETDATE())
```

and it returns 315 rows. This is the correct amount of rows.

My query in access looks like this

```
  SELECT DISTINCTROW dbo_sys_user.active, dbo_sys_user.name, dbo_sys_user.u_term_date INTO Terminations
  FROM dbo_sys_user
  WHERE (((dbo_sys_user.active)=False) AND ((dbo_sys_user.u_term_date)>=DateAdd("d",-30,Date())));
```

and pulls in 16314 rows. I cannot figure out why this is. I've tried turning on unique values and unique records. I've tried narrowing it down to 10 days. Same thing. Any insights?

Comment: umm... the obvious is that the tables have a different number of rows in the last 30 days.

Comment: It could be a date formatting thing if it isn't the number of rows as @Hogan said.  Also if you're only using a single table you don't have to qualify the table name for each field, and most of the brackets are only there because Access has some kind of OCD when it comes to brackets - `SELECT DISTINCTROW active, name, u_term_date INTO Terminations FROM dbo_sys_user WHERE active=False AND u_term_date>=DateAdd("d",-30,Date())` will work the same.

Comment: The MMSMS isn't looking at `Active` - could that affect it (although limiting it would surely return less records)?  `Active = False` could also be written as `Not Active` (just reads better in my opinion).

Comment: [GETDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would return something like `2007-04-30 13:10:02.047` while [Date](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-dd7a1f27-d957-4969-ab35-01e0bfbfed76) returns just the date?

Comment: @Hogan - in Access yes.  The Access SQL `SELECT TRUE, NOT(TRUE)` returns `-1, 0`.

Comment: @Hogan - It's the same table. dbo_sys_user in access is just a linked table to dbo.sys_user on the SQL server. The information is the same as it refreshes itself every time the Access DB is opened. So in theory shouldn't the queries return the exact same information?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Even if I add an AND statement with the active qualifier to the MSSMS query it still returns 315 results.

Comment: `u_term_date`is `Datetime` in table link? If Sql-Server is not localhost, both have date in sync (Access gets `Date()`from Client while `GetDate()`is from Sql-Server.)?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running as `GETDATE()` renders differently?

Comment: open the linked table in Access into design mode. Check the data type of the date/time column in question. It is likely being seen as a string/text column and not a date/time. If you use the standard sql driver from access and link to a sql server table with datetime2 columns, access wlll see that column as string (so you query is doing a string compare - you get way to many records). If that is indeed the case, then using the native 11 or later ODBC driver and linking to sql server will thus fixes this (the datetime2 column will now be seen as date/time on access client).

Comment: Although Albert likely reveals the underlying problem, in these cases it is often best to always step back one step at a time and **don't assume anything**.  Instead actually check the details and prove that any assumptions are correct.  If you are treating the queries as identical, expecting the same rows, then ensure that the queries are actually nearly identical as possible.  The two queries in the question are obviously not identical and it required numerous comments and conceptualizing to rule out the obvious difference.

Comment: (continued)  The Access query in the question is an INSERT query.  That should have been removed and the plain SELECT results manually inspected.  It would have been prudent to also `SELECT DateAdd("d",-30,Date()) ...`, then perhaps you might have noticed a visual difference in formatting of the values.  Even if `dbo_sys_user.active` is inconsequential in this case, it still raises red flags to others.  It would have been best to just remove the extra WHERE condition in your own testing and before posting.  I am being direct, but not to be rude rather to help hone debugging and asking skills.